# How to validate non-empty fields with Node and Passport?

Tags: node.js, validation, passport.js

I need to validate non-empty fields for a login (post request), but I get this error:

```
TypeError: req.checkBody is not a function
    at D:\IDoo projects\ExpressGenerado\config\routes.js:76:9
```

This is my route file:

```
  app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {

        res.render('signup',{message: req.flash('loginMessage')});

    }
    else{
        passport.authenticate('local-login', {
            successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
            failureRedirect : '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
            failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
        })(req,res); 
    }
});
```

And my entry point app file, after adding app.use(expressValidator) my web hangs up and doesn't validate, it does nothing:

```
var express = require('express');
var expressValidator = require ('express-validator');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer')
var constants = require('constants');
var constant = require('./config/constants');   

var port = process.env.PORT || 8042;
var passport = require('passport');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var path = require('path');

var morgan = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var now = new Date();
app.use(expressValidator); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration


app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(session({ secret: 'zomaareenstukjetekstDatjenietzomaarbedenkt' })); 
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


require('./config/routes.js')(app, passport); // load our routes and pass in our app and fully configured passport

app.listen(port);
console.log('The magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: `req.checkBody()` is provided by [`express-validator`](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator), which either isn't loaded into your Express app, or it's not loaded correctly (it should be loaded before the `POST /login` route is declared).

Comment: I added: var expressValidator = require ('express-validator'); app.use(expressValidator);  In my express app but it doesn't work. Doesn't show errors but freezes and doesn't validate.

Comment: That doesn't look right: `expressValidator` is a function that returns a middleware function, but you're not calling it. This should normally result in requests hanging, but that's not happening in your situation, which would mean that you might be adding it "too late". Can you post a (concise) version of how you're setting up your Express app, middleware and routes?

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Funny secret ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing this:

```
app.use(expressValidator);
```

However, `expressValidator` is a function that returns a middleware function, so you need to use it like this:

```
app.use(expressValidator());
```